# CSS issue: Unable to add margin to row of images (React JS)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I am unable to add margin to the row of images.
The margin is there without the css in the wide screen, but when I scale it down to mobile view, the margin gets 0.
*So I added margin 10px from css, and it doesn't make any difference*.

I am not good at css, please help.

> CSS :

```
.row__posters {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.row__poster  {
    transition: transform 300ms;
    /* preserves the aspect ratio */
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.row__poster:hover  {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

> React JSX :

```
import '../styles/Row.css';

const Row = ({ title, movies }) => {
    const posterUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
    const renderedRow = movies.map(movie => {
        return (
            <img
                className="row__poster"
                src={`${posterUrl}${movie.poster_path}`}
                alt={movie.title}
                key={movie.id} />
        );
    });
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <div className="row__posters">
                {renderedRow}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Row;
```

This is how it looks on narrow width :

[image]

> **NOTE:** Using NextJS in React.

Comment: Where have you tried adding `margin: 10px;`? It looks like that should be possible to add that CSS to `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `padding` instead of `margin`? I think the option below may work with you:

Use `padding` on the `.img_wrapper`

```
    .row__posters {
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .row__poster  {
        transition: transform 300ms;
        /* preserves the aspect ratio */
        object-fit: contain;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100px;
        // margin-right: 10px; comment this
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .row__poster:hover  {
        transform: scale(1.1);
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

You can take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-test-1-rmj9e?file=/index.js) for live demo. Hope it would work for you